# Kotlin - object type check against HashMap<String, String> shows warning

Tags: kotlin, casting

I'm trying to check `Serializable` type before casting it to `HashMap<String, String>`. But it gives following warning;

> Cannot check for instance of erased type:
>   kotlin.collections.HashMap /* =
>   java.util.HashMap */

Is there a way to check if `Serializable` is type of `HashMap<String, String>` then safe cast it?

```
params = if (it.getSerializable(ARG_PARAMS) is HashMap<String, String>) {
             it.getSerializable(ARG_PARAMS) as HashMap<String, String>
         } else null
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, you cannot check that your object has type `HashMap<String, String>` because type parameters are erased in runtime. I would like to suggest you just use a safe cast:

```
params = arguments?.getSerializable(ARG_PARAMS) as? HashMap<String, String>
```

> **Important:**
>
> It might be not clear but my code doesn't check that argument really has type `HashMap<String, String>`. You can pass `HashMap<String, Int>` and in some case, you'll get an error.
>   In my snippet you just say to the compiler: "I know that there will be `HashMap<String, String>`. Just give it to me". `params` will be null only when there is no argument or its type differs from `HashMap`.

Comment: Have you really checked the solution you've posted? At first, I was like okay, that the answer. Today I tried this in another project and boom.

Comment: yep, due to type erasure, there is no way to check that your map is actually `HashMap<String, String>` and not the `HashMap<String, Int>`. There is no such information in runtime

Comment: Then the answer should actually be `HashMap<*, *>` not `HashMap<String, String>` right? Can you please edit that part so I can re-accept it. I'm quite sure there will some people that will get it wrong as I did.

Comment: I guess no. If you'll declare it like `HashMap<*, *>` you cannot work with this map. It can be `HashMap<Any, Any>` but it not so handy

Comment: If you keep it that way, any `HashMap` with following type arguments `HashMap<String, SomeObject>` will be converted to `HashMap<String, String>` when you cast it, you know that. right? You won't get any errors, second object will simply be converted to `String`

Comment: actually not converted. Kotlin will think that `param` is `HashMap<String, SomeObject>` while it's actually `HashMap<String, SomeObject>`. So you'll get `ClassCastException` for example in this case `param!!["test"] + "test"`. So you have to know the exact type of argument in any case

Comment: Yes, you're right, not converted. I just tried to cast entries to `String` and it failed. So, I guess, I have to accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

I think the really safe answer is like this

```
val map = hashMapOf<String, String>()
arguments?.getSerializable("arg0")?.let {
    if (it is HashMap<*, *>) {
        for (item in it) {
            val key = item.key
            val value = item.value
            if (key is String && value is String) {
                map[key] = value
            }
        }
    }
}
if (map.isNotEmpty()) {
    // Serializable is HashMap<String, String>
}
```

Comment: That's safe but verbose. Also, my question was "Is there a way to check if Serializable is type of HashMap<String, String> then safe cast it?"

Comment: I know, but safe often means more verification. I change my answer. You can judge whether the map is empty, to know Serializable is type of HashMap<String, String>